# Websphere Error SRVE0206E SRVE0187E SRVE0234I SRVE0266E

Tags: java, maven, websphere

I'm currently wasting my time trying to figure out why WAS won't load my EAR and why said EAR have problem.

Context:
One of my colleague updated a version of a jar and then my m2e seem to have not picked up and was giving thousand of error (was working fine before)
I tried to check if it was Nexus (work fine). My encrypted password in the setting.xml (work fine).

I decided to try maven from the command line, everything worked fine there to. 
When I tried again in RAD (IBM eclipse) everything was now ok, no more error. 
I then proceeded to put the generated EAR in my websphere server via add and remove project and I get multiple error when I try to start the server with that ear. (see below)

I though that because it was compiled via maven cmd prompt, I might have compiled with the wrong jvm or something so I deleted my maven repo (.m2 in the user) and try to get the jar via m2e in RAD only.
It's worked until I started the server with the new EAR and got the same set of error.
Any idea on what to do to get rid of these error and have a healthy server.

Here some of the error:

> [11/10/17 12:08:51:994 EST] 00000075 annotation    W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses
>   SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation
>   scanning.
>                                    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag    at
>   java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)       ...
>
> [11/10/17 12:09:00:282 EST] 00000075 wtp           W
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.TempZipFile
>   clearTempFile Failed to delete temporary file [
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer-x86\profiles\chris_pro\wstemp\appdepl15fa68a2a21\AuthRenfClientWeb-2.0.26.war2406380505527260260.tmp
>   ] [11/10/17 12:09:00:433 EST] 00000075 SinglePathCla E   WSVR0120E: An
>   error occurred processing com.mycom.bla.testalive.TestAliveServlet
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer-x86\profiles\chris_pro\wstemp\appdepl15fa68a2a21\Client-1.61.5-SNAPSHOT.jar6655053587500024283.tmp
>   (The system cannot find the file specified.) ...
>
> SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
>                                    javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [SecurityManager]:
>   com.mycom.bla.pres.request.http.HttpSecurityManagerServlet was found,
>   but is missing another required class. SRVE0206E: This error typically
>   implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which
>   cannot be located by the server. SRVE0187E: Check your class path to
>   ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I:
>   This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the
>   classes in the application's runtime class path SRVE0234I: Application
>   class

Comment: Is the new version of the jar in the EAR?  How is the ear built? Perhaps the process which builds the ear still specifies the older jar version?

Comment: The ear is built by RAD (eclipse) with the source from the project, I've deleted everything so it should get the latest jar compile. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: The dependent jars should also be in the ear.  Unzip the ear and check to see if the updated jar is in the ear, along with all the rest.

Comment: After removing the ear from websphere and putting it back the correct jar was there. I don't understand why it didn't update correctly the first time I've removed it and re-added after.